# Are there any patterns about when to use up-to-row-start image size in glCompressedTexSubImage2D?

Tags: opengl-es

I'm using `glCompressedTexSubImage2D` to update data to an ASTC_RGBA_6x6 format texture, but it seems that for some devices one should pass in an up-to-row-start size for param `imageSize` rather than the data size according to [GL_INVALID_VALUE on glCompressedTexSubImage2D with an ASTC 8x8 texture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43336942/gl-invalid-value-on-glcompressedtexsubimage2d-with-an-astc-8x8-texture).

Does anyone know how to find out when to use up-to-row-start size, and when to use the original size on any device? Is there any API or device param that I can use?  Thank you in advance for any suggestion.

Currently I only know RedMI 4 would have this problem.

Comment: "*Is there any API or device param that I can use?*" It's a driver bug. You're not supposed to have to do this in OpenGL. Driver bugs aren't advertised; they just exist. The only way to "know" is to ask other people, or just always round the size up.

Comment: I see...I just thought that maybe this is a feature for some devices...Thank you!